# jQuery sortable containment breaks when scrolling

Tags: jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working on a widget that uses a sortable list and I'm stuck in this small issue arising when the container is scrolling. I don't want the `<li>` to go outside of the `<ul>`, so I set `containment: "parent"` when applying sortable to the list.

The containment works just fine when the container is not scrolling. But when it does, if an item is dragged to any of the ends of the list not displayed, the containment stops working as expected and the item moves beyond.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something of the sortable API, or this is just a jquery-ui bug. These are the options I have set:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: "parent",
    cursor: "move",
    items: "li",
    tolerance: "pointer",
});
```

The CSS of the container is as follows:

```
.list-holder {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omegak/2bHSG/) shows both cases, with and without scrolling.

Comment: I've simplified the fiddle. Now the list itself is the scrolling element. It's clearer now that the limit of the containment is the scrollHeight of the list instead of its height.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code to your ul

```
ul{
    max-height: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The element scrolls down because the actual list height is still present in the page even if it is not visible to us.

Here is the modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bHSG/4/)

Comment: Although this answer solves the initial issue, it causes a different one. Notice that now the list (9 elements) is not fully displayed as its overflow is hidden.